# how can i execute multiple sql queries with node oracledb plugin in one session

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am using `node oracle-db` plugin for accessing my oracle database deployed at remote server. I need to execute multiple `UPDATE` queries in one session only. I am not able to modify multiple values in database.

For now this example statement is setting 9000 for both the PIDs. I need different values for both PIDs

```
UPDATE product_master 
SET prod_bal= :bal 
WHERE pid in (100857,100861),[9000]
```

Comment: Why can't you issue two update statements, one per PID?

Comment: Are the number of pids always fixed at 2? Where did the balance value come from - another table, a calculation in JS?

Comment: @APC i am getting error and not able to execute two statement that's why i asked about executing multiple statement.

Comment: @Dan McGhan,  i have to update balance value with existing value plus a variable.

Comment: @Himanshu An existing value? Where does it come from? I'm asking because the strategy can vary. Generally speaking, if you can do this in a single SQL statement, that's going to be the most efficient solution. For example, if the values are coming from another table (with a simple calculation applied to them), you might be able to use a more flexible statement than the one Littlefoot suggested. The more we know about what you're trying to do the better we can help - the details matter.

Comment: @DanMcGhan no values are not coming from another table. I am talking about modifying the existing table values.

Comment: I have a table with some values wrt each tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this help?

```
update product_master set
  prod_bal = case when pid = 100857 then 100
                  when pid = 100861 then 200
             end
where pid in (100857, 100861);
```

100 and 200 are hardcoded values in this example; you'd use two variables, obviously.